# How to get started with Time Fixed Effects?

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

We have a time-series-dataset which we want to check for Time Fixed Effects in four waves, however we are having trouble with getting started.

Does anyone have a guide for how to work with panel data, and how we check for time fixed effects?
We have tried using the `plm` and `lm` packages. This is one of the codes we have been using:

```
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + year, data)
```

But it does not give us much. We have also used this one, but we are not sure its the correct form:

```
model <- plm(y ~ x1, index = c("country", "year"), effect = "twoways", data)
```

We are using the Quality of Government dataset, and have narrowed it down to 8 variables from the timeperiode 1996:2011.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in coding? Here is an example:

```
# Packages 
library(plm)

# Data
data("Produc", package = "plm")

# Oneway time fixed effects in plm
fe_time <- plm(pcap ~ hwy + water + util, 
               data=Produc, index=c("state", "year"), 
               model = "within", effect = "time")
# Output 
summary(fe_time)

Call:
plm(formula = pcap ~ hwy + water + util, data = Produc, effect = "time", 
    model = "within", index = c("state", "year"))

Balanced Panel: n = 48, T = 17, N = 816

Residuals:
       Min.     1st Qu.      Median     3rd Qu.        Max. 
-1.2034e-02 -1.1419e-03  3.3908e-05  1.2938e-03  1.2049e-02 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
hwy   1.0000e+00 8.3078e-08 12036953 < 2.2e-16 ***
water 1.0000e+00 2.2173e-07  4509988 < 2.2e-16 ***
util  1.0000e+00 4.7649e-08 20986941 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    6.2579e+11
Residual Sum of Squares: 0.03043
R-Squared:      1
Adj. R-Squared: 1
F-statistic: 5.45663e+15 on 3 and

 796 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Learn more about time fixed effects and examples in `R` / `plm` here https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/10-4-regression-with-time-fixed-effects.html